# Rails 3.2.5 create table issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While running migration file:

```
 def self.up
   create_table (:project_paths,:id=>false) do |t|
      t.integer :project_id
      t.integer :path_id
   end
 end
```

i got this error:

syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' create_table (:project_paths,:id=>false) do |t|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove space after `create_table`. Like this

```
def self.up
  create_table(:project_paths, :id => false) do |t|
     t.integer :project_id
     t.integer :path_id
  end
end
```